# python http.client all headers not presnt

Tags: python, scala, curl, httpclient

I have one API that I want to access for that I hit post request first with scala's scalaJ

```
  def httpPost(url : String, headers: Map[String, String], body : Map[String, String]) : HttpResponse[String] = {
    Http(url).headers(headers).postForm.params(body).asString
  }

    val reqHeader = Map( "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    val reqData = Map("login" -> "user@example.com", "password" -> "12345678")
    val response3 = httpPost(thirdUrl, reqHeader, reqData)
    println(response3.headers("location")(0))
```

here output is

```
dex/approval?req=qupgrds3z6odr5x3dtiyxi5qt
```

but when i am doing same python's http.client

```
def post_request(url, data, header, path="/"):
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url)
    conn.request("POST", path, headers=header, body=data)
    return conn.getresponse()
auth = {'login': 'user@example.com', 'password': '12345678'}
    response3 = post_request(url, header={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, data=json.dumps(auth),
                             path=location2)
```

it is returning None
when I checked the headers there was no header like location

```
[('date', 'Fri, 13 Aug 2021 13:27:05 GMT'), ('content-length', '768'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('x-envoy-upstream-service-time', '14'), ('server', 'myserver')]
```

I tried using python's requests, urllib3.request also result are same as http.client.

In curl also I am able to get location in header.

Comment: Why are you sending json body (`data=json.dumps(auth)`) with content header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ? The Http library in Scala took care of taking that map and then encoding it as per required for `form-urlencoded`, but in Python code you are just sending a json string as data. If python library has similar data encoders then you just need to remove that `json.dumps` and directly use the `auth` as `data`.

Comment: I also tried sending it as application/json result is same

Comment: The server expects a request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, why do you think that trying to send `application/json` woould work ? What is the response code in your response ? what is the response body ?

Comment: This comment resolve my issue